Theories of truth in fiction
How do various theories of truth deal with fiction?
For example, “Harry Potter is a wizard” is true within the fictional world created by J. K. Rowling. But, it is also not true because neither Harry Potter nor wizards actually exist.
Is the truth value of “Sherlock Holmes is a detective” more true because although Sherlock Holmes doesn’t exist, detectives do?
Or, if we take a real person and write historical fiction about them, ascribing to them words or actions for which there is no definitive evidence, say the speech Shakespeare’s St Crispin’s day speech placed in the mouth of Henry V. No doubt Henry said something before the Battle of Agincourt, but it almost surely wasn’t that, particularly since he spoke Middle English, not Early Modern English.

A common approach is to use the fictionalization/story operator to evaluate fictional sentences, see SEP, Fictional Discourse:"The expression “according to the story S” is the so-called “story operator”, which is a sentence operator (that is, it is the sentence as a whole that is in its scope, not just a part of the sentence, for instance the predicate). While the sentence within the scope of the story operator (here: “Pegasus is a flying horse”) may be false when taken in isolation, the complete sentence may be true."

@andrós are you ok with having things be less false: “My mother was Egyptian” (which she wasn’t) vs “My mother was a cucumber”

Nice try @DaleM but I'd class that as a category error An example that works better (IMHO) is a historical novel or movie eg. a movie on Gandhi or Churchill. There may be things in that movie that are fictionalized versions of actual history. Now a statement about Gandhi in this context could have multiple (>2) degrees of truthiness.

Gregory Currie, The Nature of Fiction (Cambridge UP, 1990) and Alberto Voltolini, How Ficta Follow Fiction: A Syncretistic Account of Fictional Entities (Springer, 2006).

We can use counterfactual conditionals (also known as subjunctive conditionals, or hypothetical conditionals) to model these statements.
Works of fiction are where we ask "what-if." "What-ifs" are the use case that counterfactual conditionals are intended for.
According to this interpretation: "Harry Potter is a wizard" really means, if Harry Potter were real as described in J.K. Rowling's books, he would be a wizard. This is a true statement, even though it happens that Harry Potter is not real.
We need counterfactual conditionals anyway to model a great many very practical things, such as, what would happen if I forgot my keys? What if we use a cheaper grade of steel in this bridge? What if I'm attacked by thieves? And so on. Since we have to have them in our ontology of statements, we might as well apply them wherever we can, so that our ontology of statements has fewer categories and is therefore simpler, and therefore better. And describing what happens to characters in works of fiction is one place we can apply them.

From a mathematical point of view, I think we would say these are true by vacuity, as in "harry potter is a wizard" because, according to JKR books, if he existed, we would be a wizard. As he clearly does not exist in our reality, the premise is false; hence he is a wizard.

@Qise but then by the same logic, Harry Potter is a whale, a whippet, a wishbone...

@Qise No, the counterfactual conditional is not the material implication. "If Harry Potter were real as described in J. K. Rowling's books, he would be an astronaut" is a false statement. The counterfactual conditional is not evaluated based on the truth values of antecedent and consequent (as material implication is); it rather sets up a model of the antecedent, and then asks whether, within that model, the consequent can be derived. Or alternatively it appeals to "closest-possible-world" logic, although personally I prefer the model interpretation.

@usul If someone write a book in which harry potter turns into a whale, then he is. As there's no (as far as I know) such thing, there's no implication between harry potter and whales, hence harry potter is not a whale.

Your examples easily translate to true sentences:

J.K. Rowling created a fictional world. In this world there exists a
person named Harry Potter and there also exist wizards.
The
sentence “Harry Potter is a wizard in Rowlings fictional world” is a
true sentence.

A. C. Doyle created some novels.
The sentence “Sherlock Holmes names a
detective in Doyle’s novels” is a true sentence.

W. Shakespeare created a play named Henry V.
The sentence
“Shakespeare in his play Henry V. let the king say ‘…’ ” is a true
sentence.



The short answer is that one can approach fiction from a linguistic and an ontological perspective. Linguistic fictions are acknowledged as literally false, but from an ontological perspective, sometimes in a context, using literal falsity to communicate truths is a tool of discourse. Consider this from the SEP's artice Fictionalism (SEP):

Often the linguistic and the ontological thesis are run together. Nolan, Restall and West (2005) say, when introducing fictionalism, “The simplest fictionalist approach to a discourse takes certain claims in that discourse to be literally false, but nevertheless worth uttering in certain contexts, since the pretence that such claims are true is worthwhile for various theoretical purposes”. (A complication that they introduce is that some fictionalists may simply be agnostic about the relevant claims.) Zoltán Gendler Szabó (2001) says, “To be a fictionalist about Fs is to think that our naïve attitude toward F-discourse is only halfway correct: we are right in thinking that we use genuine singular terms that purport to refer to Fs, but wrong in thinking that they actually succeed in referring. In engaging in F-discourse we inadvertently slip into fictional talk”. One reason that the linguistic and ontological theses are often run together is that the linguistic thesis tends to be motivated by ontological concerns.

So, the short of it then is that truth about literal fiction is understood to be relevant to the context of the fiction, and sometimes when the truth of statements is questionable in regards to being a fiction (like instrumentalism), then it is seen as a tool, and therefore it is treated quasi-fictional. This, then, would seem to suggest three categories of using truth-conditional semantics: literal fiction, instrumental fiction, and literal truth.
